# Yii2 innerJoin()

Tags: sql, yii2, inner-join

I want to implement a sql query in the following way:

```
INNER JOIN
`Product_has_ProductFeature` t ON `Product`.`id` = t.`productId` AND t.`productFeatureValueId` = 1
INNER JOIN
`Product_has_ProductFeature` t1 ON `Product`.`id` = t1.`productId` AND t1.`productFeatureValueId` = 5
```

How can I do this using `innerJoin()` or something like above mentioned?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`innerJoin()` is a [method](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-query.html#innerJoin()-detail) from the [Query](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-query.html) class.

You can try something like this.

```
$query = new \yii\db\Query;
$command = $query->innerJoin(
         'Product_has_ProductFeature',
         `Product`.`id` = t.`productId`)
     ->andWhere('t.`productFeatureValueId` = 1')
     ->createCommand();
$queryResult = $command->query();
```

Answer (score 16):

You can use the below code:

```
$model = Product::find()
->innerJoinWith('t', 'Product.id = T.productId')
->andWhere(['T.productFeatureValueId' => ''])
->innerJoinWith('t1', 'Product.id = T1.productId')
->andWhere(['T1.productFeatureValueId' => '5'])
->all();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$query = new \yii\db\Query();
$query->from(['u' => 'usr_user'])
    ->select(['u.id','p.first_name','p.last_name'])
    ->innerJoin(['i' => 'pdl_inspector'],'`u`.`id` = `inspector_id`')
    ->innerJoin(['p'=>'usr_profile'],'`p`.`user_id` = `u`.`id`')
    ->all();
```

Answer (score 1):

Tables vote_results, vote_answers, vote_questions

 Relations

 1. vote_results > vote_answers (answer_id)

 2. vote_answers > vote_questions (question_id)

```
 $matches = Results::find()
                ->select(['vote_results.id', 'COUNT(vote_results.answer_id) as MatchCount'])
                ->innerJoin('vote_answers', 'vote_results.answer_id = vote_answers.id')
                ->innerJoin('vote_questions', 'vote_answers.question_id = vote_questions.id')
                ->andWhere(['in', 'vote_results.answer_id', 31])
                ->having('COUNT(vote_results.id)>=1')
                ->orderBy('MatchCount DESC')
                ->asArray()
                ->one();
            var_dump($matches['MatchCount']);
```